# Swift: Notifying a ViewController from another using completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 ViewControllers in my app. One of them named vcA is using a method (here viewDidLoad) to talk to my networking layer (a class in my app). After finishing the networking job (which will be inferred by a completion handler) I want to notify class vcB to call a method to get some data which is provided by networking layer. 
Please take a look at below sudo code :

```
class Networking {

   static var PublicValue : SomeKindOfClass? = nil

   static func test(completionHandler : (successful : Bool) -> Void) -> Void {
      //Do some networking in background
      Network.BackgroundNetworking() {
         if result = true {
            PublicValue = SomeValue
            completionHandler(successful : true)
         }
         else {
            completionHandler(successful : false)
         }
    }
}

class vcA : UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      Networking.test(completionHandler : { (successful) in
         if successful == true {
            //Here I want to notify class vcB to call printPublicValue method
         }
      })
   }
}

class vcB : UIViewController {

  func printPublicValue() {

      print(Networking.PublicValue)
   }
}
```

Comment: Use NSNotifications

Comment: Thanks. I read about that here but I can't understand what's difference B/W NSNotifications & NSNotificationCenter & performSelector & KVO and which one is the best for my case ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I agree with @Paulw11 you should consider using NSNotifications. They are easy to set up and use and would work great in this situation. To do this, in one of your view controllers put the following code:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("nameOfNotification", object: nil)
```

In your second view controller (the one that will be receiving the notification) put:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(NameOfViewController.nameOfFunction(_:)), name: "nameOfNotification", object: nil)
```

Then you can create a function like so:

```
func nameOfFunction(notif: NSNotification) {
      //Insert code here
}
```

There is a great tutorial here if you want to go more in depth:

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/

EDIT: **Swift 3** implementation of this.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "nameOfNotification"), object: nil)
```

In your second view controller (the one that will be receiving the notification) put:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.nameOfFunction), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "nameOfNotification"), object: nil)
```

Then you can create a function like so:

```
func nameOfFunction(notif: NSNotification) {
      //Insert code here
}
```

**Swift 4** implementation of this.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "nameOfNotification"), object: nil)
```

In your second view controller (the one that will be receiving the notification) put:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.nameOfFunction), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "nameOfNotification"), object: nil)
```

Then you can create a function like so:

```
@ objc func nameOfFunction(notif: NSNotification) {
      //Insert code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That worked for me. But what would happen if I want to add observer B from class A ? What I actually want to do is to invoke method `viewDidLoad` of class B when class A finished the job through completion handler.

Comment: You should never call a view controller's `viewDidLoad` directly.  If you have a reference to an instance of B then you can set the object as the observer (the first argument to `addObserver`) but generally a class should manage its own observations.  Since you say that you want to call `viewDidLoad` it is actually that you should trigger a segue from A to B (or present B) when the data is retrieved, in which case you don't need NSNotifications

Comment: I have a UITabBarViewController, so I want it to ask networking layer to fetch all data for me. After this process I want to notify each of it's tabs that their data is ready to use. But as you know it's only the first tab's ViewController which added as an observer (other tabs did not even load yet !). Is there a way to handle this or I am completely on a wrong road ?!

Comment: You can add observers to the other view controllers too.

Answer (score 1):

In latest swift version `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Name"), object: notification)` and